# File reading with jsonp ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to get data from a json file but it fails to return anything. I'm very new at this. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garrycalliopix/EGrxV).

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://sunrise.bluechipholidays.co.uk/webservices/property/availability/apikey/demo/propertycode/ha01/date/2012-05-01/nights/5/echo/html',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(json) {
    var result = '<h3>' + json.bookable + '</h3>' +
                 '<p>Languages: ' + json.price + '</p>' +
                 '<p>Followers: ' + json.available + '</p>';
    $('#test').append(result);
}
});
```

Many thanks!

Comment: it doesn't look like the said resource is supporting jsonp

Comment: but it looks like the server is supporting CORS, if you want to support only modern browsers(IE >= 10) then you can use it

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5HDv8/1/

Comment: thats great thanks a lot works perfectly,have you any idea how to intergrate a datepicker to change the url to be date specific?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input class="datepicker" />
<div id="test"></div>
```

then

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (date) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://sunrise.bluechipholidays.co.uk/webservices/property/availability/apikey/demo/propertycode/ha01/date/' + $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $(this).datepicker('getDate')) + '/nights/5/echo/html',
            success: function (json) {
                $.each(json.data, function (_, json) {
                    var result = ' <h3> ' + json.bookable + ' </h3>' +
                        '<p>Languages: ' + json.price + '</p> ' +
                        ' <p> Followers: ' + json.available + ' </p>';
                    $('#test').html(result);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5HDv8/)

Comment: thats great thank you so much you have saved me so much time - makes perfect sense now

Comment: you have helped me so much thank you - the last thing.. how would you change the default return from the json "true" or "false" to a yes or no?

Comment: also is it easy to add a # of nights stay so they can choose a date and how long they would like to stay for?